# WebView - Threads

Tags: android, multithreading, webview

***[Edited at end. Still unsure how the answer given should be implemented.]***

I am having trouble understanding the problem with threads in an Android App. The app is basically a html webpage, and I need to go back and forth between the webview and the android app to do load and save. I want the webpage to handle all messages (because I have a nice uniform css - I am only using alert in the below for simplicity).

The Main Error when I click a button like save:

```
W/WebView: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354} called on Looper (JavaBridge, tid 109) {527ece88}, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354})
           at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2072)
           at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:903)
           at com.example.jon.androidhtmltemplate.WebAppInterface.save(WebAppInterface.java:116)
           at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
           at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354} called on Looper (JavaBridge, tid 109) {527ece88}, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354})
W/System.err:     at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2082)
              at android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript(WebView.java:903)
W/System.err:     at com.example.jon.androidhtmltemplate.WebAppInterface.save(WebAppInterface.java:116)
              at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
              at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
          Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354} called on Looper (JavaBridge, tid 109) {527ece88}, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {527e3354})
              at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:2072)
W/System.err:   ... 7 more
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(21)] "Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (21)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 135 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I get odd warnings like this at start up (should they concern me)?:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.dispatchApplyWindowInsets
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
I/Choreographer: Skipped 396 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here is my Code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.jon.androidhtmltemplate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, webview), "Android");
    }
}
```

webappinterface.java

```
package com.example.jon.androidhtmltemplate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

// This is my class to handle interaction between my webpage and the Android app
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    WebView webview;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c, WebView w) {
        mContext = c;
        webview = w;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
    public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void load(boolean isLoadExternal){
        String ret, script;

        ret = loadLocalExternal(isLoadExternal);

        script = "javascript:CallbackAndroidLoad(\"" + ret + "\")";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 /*Might need 21*/) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
        }else {
            webview.loadUrl(script);
        }
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String loadLocalExternal(boolean isExternal) {
        int length;
        String ret = "";
        File path = isExternal ? mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) : mContext.getFilesDir();
        String filename = "myappsavefile.glf";
        File file = new File(path, filename);
        FileInputStream in;
        byte[] bytes;

        try {
            length = (int) file.length();
            bytes = new byte[length];
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            in.read(bytes);
            in.close();
            ret = new String(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = "";
        }

        return ret;
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void save(boolean saveLocal, boolean saveExternal, String fileContent){
        boolean ret = true;
        String script;

        if(ret && saveLocal && !saveLocalExternal(false, fileContent + " local")) ret = false;
        if(ret && saveExternal && !saveLocalExternal(true, fileContent + " external")) ret = false;

        script = "javascript: CallbackAndroidSave(\"" + (ret ? "true" : "false") + "\")";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 /*Might need 21*/) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
        }else {
            webview.loadUrl(script);
        }
    }

    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public boolean saveLocalExternal(boolean isExternal, String fileContent) {
        boolean ret = true;
        File path = isExternal ? mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) : mContext.getFilesDir();
        String filename = "chartmygolf.glf";
        File file = new File(path, filename);
        FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
            outputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(fileContent.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph with very interesting content.</p>
<p id="id">This is another paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
<button onclick="loadLocal()">Load Local</button>
<button onclick="loadExternal()">Load External</button>

</body>
<script>
var isAndroid = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "This is on Android";

function save(){
    Android.save(true, true, "File Contents 1");
};

function loadLocal(){
    Android.load(false);
};

function loadExternal(){
    Android.load(true);
};

// ---

function CallbackAndroidLoad(fileContents){
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = fileContents.length > 0 ? "Error: Load Fail" : ("Contents: " + fileContents);
};

function CallbackAndroidSave(isSuccess){
    alert(isSuccess ? "Success" : "Failure");
};

</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT (As suggested by Sagar):**

I am new to Android development (I am a Html/Javascript programmer), so am a little confused by your post. You give 2 suggestions. I am not sure if `Callback` is a class in your second suggestion, so at the moment I will stick to your first suggestion.

**Q:** Do I need `implements Callback` on the `MainActivity` class for your ***first*** suggestion?

**Q:** with your first suggestion it appears that you are saying that I need to rewrite my `public class WebAppInterface` functions whenever there is a call back to the html page. Is that right?

So I am guessing my new `load` function will become:

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public void load(boolean isLoadExternal){
    String ret, script;

    ret = loadLocalExternal(isLoadExternal);

    script = "javascript:CallbackAndroidLoad(\"" + ret + "\")";

    // This is the only bit of the function with a call back in it
    // so I need to do the special stuff on this bit alone
    activityObj.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 /*Might need 21*/) {
                 webview.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
            }else {
                webview.loadUrl(script);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

**Q:** What is `activityObj`? Where does it come from? If it has to be passed with a calling function, how do I do it?

**Q:** Is my comment in the code correct: `This is the only bit of the function with a call back in it so I need to do the special stuff on this bit alone`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavascriptInterface`methods are called on background thread and not on  UI thread. While dealing with UI, you need to use main UI thread.

Since you are executing it in separate class, you need to pass `Activity` object and then in all your `JavascriptInterface` methods:

Change the `WebAppInterface` class as follows:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Activity activityObj;
    WebView webview;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Activity activityObj, WebView w) {
        mContext = c;
        this.activityObj = activityObj;
    }   
    ...
}
```

and runOnUiThread as follows:

```
activityObj.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19 /*Might need 21*/) {
                webview.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
        }else {
            webview.loadUrl(script);
        }
    }
});
```

**Alternatively you can implement some callback interface and perform action in Activity itself as follows:**

```
public interface Callback {
    void loadLocalExternal(boolean isExternal);
    //define other methods.
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback{

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, this), "Android");
    }

    @Override
    public void loadLocalExternal(boolean isExternal){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Do your action here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**WebAppInterface.java**

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    private final Callback callback;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c, Callback callback) {
        mContext = c;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public String loadLocalExternal(boolean isExternal) {
        callback.loadLocalExternal(isExternal);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am a little confused. That is why i have taken a little while to respond. I understand what you are saying about doing this stuff on the UI thread. That makes sense, but I am still a little unsure how to implement it. Since there is a lot of code in my question to your reply, I have updated my original question which references your answer. It is at the bottom starting: **EDIT (As suggested by Sagar):**

Comment: Thanks Sagar for the addition to your answer, it helped me a lot. From what you added to your answer it looked like the function constructor of the WebAppInterface was doing a cast from a Context to a Activity. I think I need the Context for some other stuff I want to do later on so I kept mContext as a Context and did a cast on the fly `((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`. It seemed to work. So your answer significantly added to my knowledge of Android programming.

Comment: @Rewind No problem. Actually you don't need to have the object as Context, you simply replace contextObj with ActivityObj because in the hierarchy, `Activity` extends `Context`. But other way around is not possible. If someone simply passes application context, rahter than `Activity.this`, then `((Activity) mContext)` will cause crash.